# sign up form do not send Email to users

Tags: php, forms, email, mysqli

I have this form which sign up users and send email to verify emails is correct and exists the users sign up OK but the "Verification Email" did not sent to the user email

**here is the PHP Code**

```
    <?php

if (isset($_POST['submited'])) {
    $msg = "";

    $RFname = clean_text($_POST['RFname']);
    $RLname = clean_text($_POST['RLname']);
    $USERname = clean_text($_POST['UserName']);
    $USERpassword = $_POST['UserPass'];
    $USERpassword2 = $_POST['UserPassConfirm'];
    $USERemail = $_POST['UserEmail'];
    $USERwebsite = $_POST['WebSite'];
    $hash = clean_text(md5(rand(0, 1000)));
    $checkEmail = $db->query("select * from loginaccess where Email ='" . $USERemail . "'");
    $checkUID = $db->query("select * from loginaccess where Uname ='" . $USERname . "'");


    if ($USERpassword !== $USERpassword2) {
        $msg = "<span style='color:#F00; font-size:14px; font-weight:bold;'>Passwords did not match</span>";
    } elseif ($checkEmail->num_rows == 1) {
        $msg = "<span style='color:#F00; font-size:14px; font-weight:bold;'>This email already taken</span>";
    } elseif ($checkUID->num_rows == 1) {
        $msg = "<span style='color:#F00; font-size:14px; font-weight:bold;'>This User name already taken</span>";
    } elseif (empty($_SESSION['6_letters_code']) || strcasecmp($_SESSION['6_letters_code'], $_POST['6_letters_code']) != 0) {
        $msg = "<span class='errorMessges'>Human code verification invalid</span>";
    } else {
        $putData = "insert into loginaccess (id, FUname, LUname, Uname, Pword, Email, Website, hash) value ('', '$RFname', '$RLname', '$USERname', '$USERpassword', '$USERemail', '$USERwebsite', '$hash')";
        $inputResult = $db->query($putData) or die ('$db->error');
        if ($inputResult) {
            $msg = "<span class='successMessgaes'>You have been successfully registered</span>";

            // Send email to our user 
            $to = '$USERemail';
            $subject = 'Signup | Verification';
            $message = "

        Welcome to Learning and share.

    Before you can use your new account you must activate it - this ensures the e-mail address you used is valid and belongs to you.  To activate your account, click the link below or copy and paste the whole thing into your browser's location bar:

    -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
    http://www.yourwebsite.com/verify.php?email='.$USERemail.'&hash='.$hash.'
    -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 

    Once you've successfully activated your account, you can throw away this e-mail.

    Thanks!

    The Learning and share staff


    ";
            $headers = 'From:noreply@learning.com' . "\r\n";
            mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
        } else {
            $msg = "<span class='errorMessges'>There was an error please try again later</span>";
        }
    }
}
?>
```

and this is HTML Code

```
<form action="<?php $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post">

    <table width="762" border="0" cellspacing="5" cellpadding="5">
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2" class="socialAndPeopleByName">Personal information</td>
            <td colspan="2"><span class="socialAndPeopleByName">Account information</span></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td width="91" class="registrationInfo"><span class="red">*</span> First name</td>
            <td width="203"><label for="textfield"></label>
              <span id="sprytextfield1">
              <input name="RFname" type="text" class="registrationFeild" id="textfield"/>
              <span class="textfieldRequiredMsg"><br>
              First name  is required.</span></span></td>
            <td width="148"><span class="red">*</span><span class="registrationInfo"> User name</span></td>
            <td width="255"><span id="sprytextfield5">
              <input name="UserName" type="text" class="registrationFeild" id="textfield5"/>
              <span class="textfieldRequiredMsg"><br>
              User name is required.</span></span></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="registrationInfo"><span class="red">*</span> Last name</td>
            <td><span id="sprytextfield2">
              <input name="RLname" type="text" class="registrationFeild" id="textfield2"/>
              <span class="textfieldRequiredMsg"><br>
              Last name is required.</span></span></td>
            <td><span class="red">*</span><span class="registrationInfo"> Password</span></td>
            <td><span id="sprypassword1">
            <input name="UserPass" type="password" class="registrationFeild" id="textfield7"/>
            <span class="passwordRequiredMsg"><br>
            Password is required.</span><span class="passwordMaxCharsMsg"><br>
            Password can't be more then 20 letter</span><span class="passwordMinCharsMsg"><br>
            Password can't be less then 6 letter</span></span></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="registrationInfo"><span class="red">*</span> Valid email</td>
            <td><span id="sprytextfield3">
            <input name="UserEmail" type="text" class="registrationFeild" id="textfield3"/>
            <br>
            <span class="textfieldRequiredMsg">Valid email is required.</span><span class="textfieldInvalidFormatMsg">Invalid email format.</span></span>
            </td>
            <td><span class="red">*</span><span class="registrationInfo"> Confirm Password</span></td>
            <td><span id="sprypassword2">
              <input name="UserPassConfirm" type="password" class="registrationFeild" id="textfield8"/>
              <span class="passwordRequiredMsg"><br>
              Please confirm your password</span></span></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="registrationInfo">Web site</td>
            <td><span id="sprytextfield4">
              <input name="WebSite" type="text" class="registrationFeild" id="textfield4"/>
              <br>
              <span class="textfieldInvalidFormatMsg">Invalid format</span></span></td>
            <td><span class="registrationInfo"><span class="red">*</span> Prove you are human</span></td>
            <td><img src="includes/captcha.php?rand=<?php echo rand(); ?>" align="absmiddle" id='captchaimg'/> <a
                    href="javascript: refreshCaptcha();"><img src="images/refreshIcon.jpg" alt="Refresh" width="18"
                                                              height="25" border="0" align="absmiddle"/></a> <input
                    name="6_letters_code" type="text" class="registrationFeildSmall" id="6_letters_code"/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="3"><?php if (!empty($msg)) {
                    echo $msg;
                } ?></td>
            <td><input name="submited" type="submit" class="signUpItem" id="submited" value=""/></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

what happen after user sign up :

1. the new user inserts successfully into the database.
2. the users get the message "You have been successfully registered".

**problem** : here is the problem the user never get his Verification email.

Comment: can I understand why you rate me down please comment before rating u (....)

Comment: *"It doesn't work"* and *"please need help on this"* [doesn't explain the problem](http://stuck.include-once.org/#help3) enough. You need to elaborate on your input, expected and actual outcomes, or concretise error messages. Otherwise this is not considered as a question.

Comment: The [`mail` function](http://php.net/mail) has a return value. Check it to know about your problem early. Then actually verify what you do in case it fails, e.g. `var_dump($to, $subject, $message, $headers);` - This just needs basic debugging first. Isolate the problem for that and get into the know which parameters are wrong. It's better you enable yourself spotting these issues so that next time you run into a problem you know a little more how to deal with such problems.

Comment: "please debug my code for me" is not a well-suited kind of questions for SO

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change:

```
$to='$USERemail';
```

To:

```
$to = $USERemail;
```

PHP doesn't allow string interpolation of variables in single quotes.

Comment: thanks @tehlulz yes this was the problem it worked fine now

Answer (score 1):

You wrote you have a problem sending out the confirmation email. You need to check if it basically works or not, and if not, provide yourself some debug information.

The [`mail` function](http://php.net/mail) has a return value:

> Returns `TRUE` if the mail was successfully accepted for delivery, `FALSE` otherwise.
>
> It is important to note that just because the mail was accepted for delivery, it does NOT mean the mail will actually reach the intended destination.

Make use of return values to write more stable code. Otherwise you keep sitting in the dark.

A rough example:

```
...

$headers = 'From:noreply@example.com' . "\r\n"; 
$send = mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
if (!$send) {
    echo "Failed to send Email:\n";
    var_dump($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
    die();
}
```

Then locate the actual problem. If it's reported that the email was sent, but you do not see it delivered, check your outgoing mail error log.

Comment: Thanks for your answer I have understand a lot from it.